# Strongly connected components algorithm clarification

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a graph G, SCC can be found using this algorithm:

```
DFS(G)   // compute finish times f[u]
GT = Transpose(G)
DFS(GT)  // considering vertices in order of decreasing f[u]
```

What I'm trying to understand is: *why the 2nd DFS has to be done in order of decreasing finish times, is there a way to prove it? Why, e.g., considering the vertices in increasing order doesn't compute the right SCC?*

I already read some answers and examples here on SO but they didn't help. The question is how to prove this fact.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.
The order of finish times is to prevent the visit of vertices outside the component through cross edges (of the original graph) since these, in the transposed graph, connect 2 nodes `u` and `v` if `d[u] < d[v]`.

However thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so you only want a counter example ?

Let's just take the graph with 2 vertices (1 and 2) and one link from 1 to 2 (but not from 2 to 1).
The SCC of this graph are {1} and {2}.
Starting the DFS from 1, we go to 2, where the DFS can't expand more, so 2 is finished, and 1 is finished since the only edge from 1 goes to 2. The order is 2 ; 1.
Let's transpose the graph, and don't follow the algorithm on purpose by starting the DFS of the transposed graph on 2 (we should start with 1).
From 2, we can go to 1 on the transpose graph. The DFS gives 1 and 2 as checked, so {1, 2} would be a SCC, although it isn't a SCC.

**This counter example proves that we can't take the order we want for the second DFS, but that doesn't prove that we will get a wrong result every time.**

For example, let's take the same graph with a link between 1 and 2, and also a link from 2 to 1. The only SCC of this graph is {1, 2}.
Let's start the first DFS on 1. This also gives the order 2 ; 1.
Now, if we start the DFS of the transposed graph on 1 again, we would get {1, 2} as a SCC.
So for this case, we have the attended result.

TL;DR : There is no equivalence between "getting the good result" and "take the vertices in descending order". But the latter implies the former.